# What makes this a bad question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Copying Subscribers of Events to Derived Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135547/copying-subscribers-of-events-to-derived-object)

It seems I can never ask a good question on Stack Overflow. On the Maths Stack Exchange site or even Christianity Stack Exchange site, I get reputation, many thumbs up and reputation for asking less intelligent questions, and ones I have definitely spent less time writing. Can someone explain, in-depth, what makes this a bad question, deserving downvotes, and how should I have gone about writing it to improve it?

Comment: Explain the purpose of the question. What is your problem? If you did that maybe someone could explain how to solve it in an entirely different way. Given how difficult it is to get it things to work your way perhaps everyone else is solving this problem entirely differently so they never encounter this issue.

Comment: The question reads a bit like a XY problem. It seems you are trying to achieve something that isn't intended. Maybe there is a completely different way to solve the whole problem if you don't focus on getting the invocation list but on the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Indeed, this question seems to jump right into the middle of a story. This is because it is about a particular solution you chose to pursue. Questions work better when they ask about a problem AND a solution you picked, not just the solution. That gives more context and allows people to follow your train of thought (and maybe turn it around).

Comment: Note: not that I consider it to be a particular **bad** question... but when a question is on the edge and is certainly not really good, you get a whole lot of people not voting and a couple downvoting. The name of the game really is to make a question in such a state that people are willing to upvote, then a downvote or two don't matter.

Comment: Quote: "I'm deriving from a class in System".  Everybody knows what that namespace looks like.  So what is the point of posting a snippet that doesn't?  And can't repro the problem either?  What you're trying to do has pretty grave stability and security implications, never make it look like you have something to hide.

Comment: Yes, it smells very X/Y, you're trying to do something that is not a good idea (as witnessed by the fact you have to abuse reflection to accomplish it). Now, sometimes you have to do this, sad fact is. However, we have no idea if this is the case. You've got 3/4 a good question--what you attempted, what happened, why it didn't work for you. But you missed the first thing all questions need--what you are trying to accomplish. That's different than what you did, and helps answerers help you reach your ultimate goal.

Comment: The Maths Stack Exchange site is a special case. They don't have any (enforced) standards and will allow any question as long as it is not blatantly off-topic. Like [straight homework dumps](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2352049/angle-chasing-in-quadrilaterals).

Comment: And is the reason this is getting downvoted because it is also a bad question or because it features a bad question?

Comment: This question is getting downvoted because Meta gets questions like this very often. Pretty much everything the answer has is already detailed in [ask].

Answer (score 22):

### Reader doesn't know what you know

When asking a question, you need to ***keep in mind and assume*** that the reader ***does not know anything*** about what you're doing or what you're attempting to do.

A question that seems "unclear" or "confusing" will most likely attract downvotes than anything else.

---

### A question/answer is like the first few lines of a book

Keep in mind, writing a question is much like writing a book. A book should captivate the reader within the first few lines, and not confuse them.

Here is the first description of the problem you give.

> Since the child can't do everything the parent class can do to the event, I can't use .GetInvocationList(). Therefore, how would I be able to get around this in a simple way so that I can copy the subscribers of an event, made in a base class, in a child class?

As you can see, you give no context as to what you're trying to achieve. Context is very important to help the reader understand where you're going with your code example.

However, you ***dive right into*** the issue talking about how the "child can't do everything the parent class can do to the event". It's almost as if you *skipped* the *introduction* and went straight to chapter 5.

Here are my initial questions when I see this:

1. What are you trying to achieve?
2. What do you mean by "can't do everything" ?
3. What do you mean "doesn't work" ? Are you getting any errors ?
4. What is your `base class` is that a reference to the Parent ?

---

### Conclusion

Generally speaking, before asking a question go over your post again and pretend you're someone that knows nothing about your problem and ask yourself if it's easy to understand.

Depending on the reader, some may understand and/or guess as to what you're trying to achieve, while others may not.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. Is this the same reason why this question has been so heavily downvoted?

Comment: Nobody can tell you that for sure.  Seriously.  People are not required to make their reasons for voting (up or down) public.